# Run ruby file in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've created a file `ebm.rb` script to add new entries to a database in rails.

The file is very long, and uses some rails models.

Can I easily execute  `ebm.rb` in the `rails console`?

I tried something with `load` and `require`, but that didn't work. My `ebm.rb` file is located in `C:\Sites\ebm` and my rails project in `C:\Sites\rublesql`.

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for a seed file.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed.... It's a decent question, and the first result on my internet search ... I've edited it slightly to make it clearer (not that the original was that unclear) and nominated for reopen...

Comment: Agreed @Carpetsmoker, nominated it for reopening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run the code in the file in the context of your rails app with

```
rails runner
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner